# MongoDB in Java, How to retrieve nestled document from array contained in another document?

Tags: java, mongodb

How can I retrieve distinct actors from a nestled array in a film document as seen in the image. The code below returns the entire document for each film the actor appears in, nothing I've tried so far works.

Thanks!

```
MongoCursor test = filmCollection.find(Filters.and(
Filters.eq("Actors.First name", Pattern.compile("^"+firstName+".*")),
Filters.eq("Actors.Last name", Pattern.compile("^"+lastName+".*")))).iterator();
```

[image: example document]

Comment: You can get distinct items using the [db.collection.distinct()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/index.html) _or_ using the aggregation's [$group stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html#retrieve-distinct-values). There are equivalent APIs  with Java driver.

Comment: Thanks! Solved it with $group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by first unpacking all the nested arrays with unwind, only matching the target name and finally grouping

```
db.films.aggregate([{
    $unwind: "$Actors"

}, {
    $match: {
        "Actors.First name": {$regex: "^name.*"}
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$Actors.actorId",
        "first": {
            $first: "$Actors.First name"
        },
        "last": {
            $first: "$Actors.Last name"
        }
    }
}])
```